# ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s). Type "SETX /?" for usage

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-10-preview

I am trying to set my environment variable for my system using
`setx PATH="%PATH%;c:\PROGRA~2\Vim\vim74;"` command in cmd. I get `ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).` Is the 8.3 filename causing the error?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try the full Win32 name? please add which console you are using.

Comment: Did you try it without the quotes?

Comment: Try it with a space instead of the `=`. **But also** note that the system environment variable `PATH` is the *global part* of the `PATH` environment variable. `%PATH%` is the system environment variable plus your personal `PATH`. If your personal `PATH` is non-null, your command will propagate your personal `PATH` into the global `PATH`.